Openapi generate Resource and no MultipartFile
I use openapi to generate code for my controller on my kotlin spring project.
so i use the kotlin-spring module of openapi-generator.
I need to upload many files in one endpoint call.
Here is my spec yaml:
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Create a resourcesBatch to import
  version: 24.47.0
paths:
  /resourcesBatch:
    post:
      operationId: createResourcesBatch
      tags:
        - CommandResourcesBatch
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                attachedFiles:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
              required:
                - attachedFiles
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: uuid

that generate a List<Resource> for attachedFiles but the java implementation would be List<MultipartFile> and i think it's better cause it's simpler to deserialize and use.
That what is generate exactly :
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("\${api.base-path:}")
class ResourcesBatchApiController() {

    @Operation(
        summary = "",
        operationId = "createResourcesBatch",
        responses = [
            ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Created", content = [Content(schema = Schema(implementation = java.util.UUID::class))])
        ]
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = [RequestMethod.POST],
        value = ["/resourcesBatch"],
        produces = ["application/json"],
        consumes = ["multipart/form-data"]
    )
    fun createResourcesBatch(
       @Parameter(description = "") @Valid @RequestPart("attachedFiles", required = true) attachedFiles:kotlin.collections.List<org.springframework.core.io.Resource>
    ): ResponseEntity<java.util.UUID> {
        return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED)
    }
}

So how i can get
attachedFiles:kotlin.collections.List<org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile>

Thank you guys for response
